# for loop giving unexpected result in C

Tags: c

I'm unable to understand the following for loop. Please help me. Thanks for your time. I'm unable to understand how the for loop becomes true in the first iteration. if s[0] = "d", then how "d" will be treated like "true".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "d";
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i]; i++)
        printf("%c %c %c %c",s[ i ], *(s+i), *(i+s), i[s]);
    return 0;
}
```

```
output : dddd
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With arrays, why is it the case that a\[5\] == 5\[a\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a)

Comment: I'm unable to understand how the for loop becomes true.

Comment: if s[0] = "d", then how it gets treated like "true"

Comment: @AlexSparrow `s[0] = 'd'`, not `"d"`, very different. Hopefully my answer can clear things up a bit.

Comment: `'d' != 0`, so it is true when treated as a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted  designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator []  is that E1[E2] is identical
>   to (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently,a pointer to
>   the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2]
>   designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

So `s[i]` is equivalent to `*( s + i )` that from the mathematical point of view is equivalent to `*( i + s )` and in C may be rewritten like `i[s]` because in any case the expression is considered like `*( i + s )`.

Thus all these constructions

```
s[ i ] 
*(s+i) 
*(i+s) 
i[s]
```

are equivalent in C and denote the `i-th` element of the array `s`.

As for your comment to my answer

> Could you please explain how the for loop becomes true during the
>   initial iteration?

then the array `s` is initialized by the string literal `"d"`.

```
char s[ ] = "d";
```

A string literal includes into itself the terminating zero character `'\0'`. So the declaration above can be in fact equivalently rewritten the following way

```
char s[ ] = { 'd', '\0' };
```

As the first element of the array is not equal to zero (it is equal to the character `'d'`) then the condition `s[i]` that is equivalent to the condition `s[i] != 0` is true when `i` is equal to `0`.

And a quote regarding to the for-statement (6.8.5 Iteration statements)

> 4 **An iteration statement causes a statement called the loop body to
>   be executed repeatedly until the controlling expression compares equal
>   to 0**. The repetition occurs regardless of whether the loop body is
>   entered from the iteration statement or by a jump.1

Comment: Could you please explain how the for loop becomes true during the initial iteration?

Comment: Thanks @VladfromMoscow

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you mismatched your quotes: 
>> Then the array s is initialized by the string literal "d'.

Comment: So, if I simply say s[i] in the for loop(condition checking), then it will become equivalent to s[i] != 0, right?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Thanks. I have updated the typo.

Comment: Any non zero value is the true and zero is false. S[i] is just the integer value (char is just the integer)

Answer (score 1):

`char s[] = "d";` declares a string literal, which is zero-terminated. In your for loop the break condition is `s[i]` which means it will run until it gets to the NULL character (which will be the second character).

Comment: Thanks for your time @mnistic

Answer (score 1):

`char s[] = "d"` initializes `s` to an array containing the character `'d'` followed by a null terminator (`'\0'`).

In the initial iteration of the for loop, we check `s[0]` to determine whether to run the loop. This checks the first character of `s`, which is `'d'`. In C, any character besides `'\0'` is considered true, and `'\0'` is considered false. (This is because C treats characters similar to integers, where 0 is false and any other int is true.)

So the for loop initially checks `'d'`, which is a true value, and runs the loop.

On the second iteration, it looks at `s[1]`, which is `'\0'`. This is a false value, so it doesn't run the loop a second time.

Comment: This is also a very good explanation @CoffeeTableEspresso, I wish I could mark two answers right.Thanks for your time, brother.

Comment: @AlexSparrow you can upvote as many answers as you want (by clicking the up arrow on the left side of an answer by its score).